# Как запретить доступ по внешнему IP nginx?

Tags: nginx, nginx-faq

Сейчас сайт доступен по внешнему ip: http://12.34.56.78
Как запретить доступ по эх этому ип, и оставить доступ только с доменного имени?

Comment: А разве по имени хоста не перейдет оно все-равно по ip?

Comment: @gil9red, именно «по ip» и «перейдёт». только в http-заголовке `host` будет фигурировать доменное имя.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

например, создайте «заглушку»:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name 12.34.56.78;
  # какие-то директивы
}
```

которая, например, будет перенаправлять на нужное доменное имя:

```
  return 301 http://доменное.имя$request_uri;
```

(это вместо строки `# какие-то директивы`).

Comment: Редирект в заглушке не очевидная вещь, может привести к обслуживанию чужого трафика, например (чужой домен прописан в DNS с IP нашего веб-сервера).

Comment: @raciasolvo, предложенная «заглушка» будет обрабатывать запросы, в которых заголовок `host` **содержит указанный ip-адрес**. если чужой домен ссылается на этот ip-адрес, то при http-запросе к этому чужому домену в заголовке `host` будет именно он, а не ip-адрес, то есть предложенная «заглушка» не «сработает», вопреки вашим опасениям.

Comment: Вы правы, в заглушку попадает все, что будет пытаться получить доступ по IP. Для описанного мною случая нужна будет еще одна, но другая заглушка. Я не правильно привел пример к проблеме - а нужно ли перенаправление чужого трафика? Может безопаснее поставить `return 444` вместо редиректа? При получении  нового IP я сталкивался с ситуацией, когда сторонний, не самый хороший трафик, идет именно по IP. Хотя, наверное, это вопрос каждой конкретной ситуации. И трафик может оказаться не чужим. Ответ плюсую.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы используете настройки по умолчанию, то все запросы обрабатываются одной секцией server, который действителен для любого доменного имени или адреса.

Вот так выглядит "универсальный" сервер и так быть не должно :) То есть это не то, что вам хочется. Замените _ на нужное вам доменное имя.

```
server_name _;
```